# Syntax error in SQL statement when using Hibernate Envers

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I just added hibernate envers to my spring boot project.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
  <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here my Entity:

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class MyTable {
...
}
```

The flyway migration script creates the corresponding tables:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_AUD (
    ID BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    REV             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    REVTYPE         TINYINT,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id, REV )
);

create table REVINFO (
    REV  INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    REVTSTMP BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY ( REV )
);

alter table MY_TABLE_AUD
   add constraint FK5ecvi1a0ykunrriib7j28vpdj
   foreign key (REV)
   references REVINFO;
```

As soon as I try to save an entity to `MY_TABLE`, I get the following error:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL FROM[*] DUAL "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual [42001-197]
```

The error seems to be related to the sequence which is supposed to generate the `REV` value.

Comment: What database and dialect are being used here?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you have an invalid sql statement.

https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html#c42001

My thought is your table name is not "MyTable" and is some other table name. Check to see if your table name is an h2 protected keyword and therefore not a valid table name.  You may need to change your model class name.